# How to transform an object structure where a property value is going to serve as key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, merge

For example I have this object:

```
let obj = { id: "12", name: "abc" };
```

I need to transform this obj to be like this:

```
{ "12": "abc" }; // the key is the value of “id”
```

This way, I will be able to access name through id as below:

```
let name = obj["12"];
```

**Edit:**

I need to transform the below object:

```
 obj = {
        "groups": [{
                "groupId": 2345,
                "status": 2
            }, {
                "groupId": 3456,
                "status": 5
            }
        ]
     }
```

To:

```
obj ={
        "2345":2,
        "3456":5
    }
```

this will allow me to easily look for the status using the `groupId`.
For example: to get status 5, I can look to it this way `obj["2345"]`

Comment: `obj = {[obj.id]:obj.name}`

Comment: Is the OP looking for a generic, recursively working approach which can handle nested data structures? Cause a solution for the provided example should not be that difficult to come up with by the OP himself.

Comment: see also ... [Object initializer :: Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) and [Computed object property names and destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring)

Comment: If you have only a single object, why would you need to access its name through its id? Or do you actually have multiple objects (e.g. in an array)? Then please [edit] your question to include the actual data structure.

Comment: you need to give more information about why you can't do this there is no problem here

Comment: @Bergi I provided more details

Comment: @AliAlAmine Did you try a loop?

Comment: Also reduce can help you to achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP can directly resolve/flatten the `groups` array items into the target object/structure ... from ...

```
{
  groups: [{
    groupId: 2345,
    status: 2,
  }, {
    groupId: 3456,
    status: 5,
  }],
}
```

... into ...

```
{
  "2345": 2,
  "3456": 5
}
```

... a function might implement an approach based on both [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which, for each iteration, does aggregate the target object by a new key-value pair, and where the according data (`groupId`, `status`) is delivered by each item of the iterated `groups` array. The finally returned `target` object is the reducer function's accumulator and gets initially provided as simple empty object literal `{}`.

There are two implementations of the above described approach. The first one ... `resolveGroupsVerbose` ... might be easier to read/comprehend by beginners because the code explicitly states what is done, the second approach ... `resolveGroups`  ... makes use of [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which results in a more compact code ...

```js
// One and the same approach ...

// ... without any destructuring and destructuring assignments.
function resolveGroupsVerbose(value) {
  return value.groups.reduce((target, groupsItem) => {

    // create new object ...
    const obj = {};

    // ... and assign new key-value data
    //     derived from `groupsItem`.
    obj[groupsItem.groupId] = groupsItem.status;

    // return the aggregated target.
    return Object.assign(target, obj);

  } , {});
}

// ... with destructuring assignments.
function resolveGroups({ groups }) {
  return groups
    .reduce((target, { groupId, status }) =>
      Object.assign(target, { [groupId]: status }), {}
    );
}

const sample = {
  groups: [{
    groupId: 2345,
    status: 2,
  }, {
    groupId: 3456,
    status: 5,
  },
]};

console.log(
  'resolveGroupsVerbose(sample) ...',
  resolveGroupsVerbose(sample)
);
console.log(
  'resolveGroups(sample) ...',
  resolveGroups(sample)
);

// expected:  resolveGroups(sample) ... {
//   "2345": 2,
//   "3456": 5
// }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```